# sorted on basis of two keys, descending order sort for first and ascending for second

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of tuple:

`lst = [(1,2), (3,2), (1,3), (3,4)]`

I want to sort this list in **descending order** on basis of first key, but for **same values of this key**, list should be sorted on basis of second key but in **ascending order**.

But if I do:

`srt_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda val: (val[0], val[1]), reverse = True)`

It gives me:

`[(3, 4), (3, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2)]`

But List I am looking for is

`[(3, 2), (3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3)]`

**EDIT**

Apologies, I thut I have given all info needed!!!!

Kindly consider, following as my List:

`[('1', '3:00 PM'), ('1', '3:00AM'), ('2', '1:00 AM'), ('2', '2:00 AM')]`

`srt_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda val: (val[0], val[1]), reverse = True)`

Gives:
`[(2, '2:00 PM'), (2, '2:00 AM'), (2, '1:00 AM'), (1, '3:00 PM'), (1, '3:00 AM')]`

Required is:

`[(2, '2:00 AM'), (2, '2:00 PM'), (1, '3:00 AM'), (1, '3:00 PM')]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

negate the second key:

```
lst = [(1,2), (3,2), (1,3), (3,4)]

print(sorted(lst,key=lambda x: (x[0],- x[1]),reverse=True))
[(3, 2), (3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Or the first and remove the reverse:

```
print(sorted(lst,key=lambda x: -x[0])

[(3, 2), (3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

sorting from lowest to highest will put the  lower second values first but using `-x[0]` will put the higher first elements first.

Based on your edit you need to  cast `x[0]` to int and parse the times into datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

lst = [('1', '3:00 PM'), ('1', '3:00 AM'), ('2', '1:00 AM'), ('2', '2:00 AM')]

print(sorted(lst,key=lambda x: (-int(x[0]), datetime.strptime(x[1], "%H:%M %p"))))
[('2', '1:00 AM'), ('2', '2:00 AM'), ('1', '3:00 PM'), ('1', '3:00 AM')]
```

Comment: My apolgies, I thut, details I am giving were enuf, but Second field happen to be time string. pls consider `[('1', '3:00 PM'), ('1', '3:00AM'), ('2', '1:00 AM'), ('2', '2:00 AM')]` as my List. Updating question as well

Comment: no prob, I presumed `'3:00AM'` was a typo, you must always sort digits as actual ints/floats.. the same with times as `"1000" > "2"` is False when dealing with strings

Comment: what if both keys are srings? how can we negate a string?
lst = tuple(('a','b'), ('b','a'))